# Read dead iPhone's files?

Tags: iphone, recovery, hdd

I have a broken iPhone 4S with iOS 8.1.1 jailbroken. It fell a lot, and the battery connector (I forgot to screw it back in) ripped out of it and the screen is broken so even if I place it and hold it with my fingers against the pins, it turns on but the screen is not possible to see as it just flickers. It also does not turn on all the way and right when it does, it just restarts so I can't connect it to my computer.

Question, how can I actually read the iPhone's HDD? Is it built in the motherboard? Is there anyway to buy something that would connect to it to read the files?

The reason for this is, I have about 300 songs on there and a lot of photos and the music has been copied to a different folder from Filza. I am comfortable taking the phone apart, it actually is apart right now pretty much and I just need help reading the files of a dead iPhone.

Comment: iPhone HDD?  I about edited to correct, but the proper terminology is likely "how do I read the phone's file system?"  Since the file system is in RAM, there is no HDD.

Comment: The storage in iPhone is NAND flash memory, not RAM. iPhone also contains RAM, but a defining characteristic of RAM is that data is lost when the memory is not powered.

Comment: @tubedogg good point.. I think I meant to type memory

Comment: Yeah, by HDD I meant its memory where all the files are.

Answer (score 2):

If the connector is 'ripped out', the only way to access the data would be to 1) hope the internals are still intact after all that falling--and other--damage, and 2) find another iPhone 4s, and transfer the 'old' inner stuff to the new phone and go from there. This is not a trivial operation (see the iFixit guides), and I would only attempt this if 1) the data is irreplaceable, and 2) you have familiarity with such work.

Comment: So is the inner stuff built in the motherboard? Replacing the motherboard on a new phone will basically replace the whole system?

Comment: Flash memory is soldered to the motherboard. Outside of a high tech factory setting, you're not getting it off there.

Comment: So I could just transfer the old motherboard into a new phone, right?